# Thread auto name change

Tags: java, multithreading

Im wanting to create a new thread everytime a client connects to my server.
I have a counter named 'clients' which increments everytime someone connects.
So I want the thread that deals with the client to be named C+client number. For example C2 or C4.
I have this at the moment:

```
Thread C =new Thread()
```

It wont let me replace it with:

```
Thread ("C" + clients) =new Thread()
```

It says the left hand side needs to be a varible.
I have also tried:

```
String threadName = "C" + clients;
Thread threadName =new Thread()
```

But I get the message saying 'Duplicate local varible threadName.

So how would I go about making a new name for a thread in a loop which increments?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need thread safety on your count so use an AtomicInteger for it:

```
 AtomicInteger numClients = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

For your main problem you seem to be confusing *variable declaration*, *variable assignment* and *object construction* as your code is very scrambled. Try:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread("C "+numClients.getAndIncrement());
```

Do some reading up on the three things I listed above and it should help your understanding.

Comment: Maybe suggest an `Executor` and a custom `ThreadFactory` with your approach?

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Normally I'd recommend that but in this case I'm keeping it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thank you. As you can tell, Im new to programming and have a networking piece of coursework using threads but haven't been taught much at all. So thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using an `Executor` to make thread management easier.

Start with something simple like [newCachedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29), and supply a [ThreadFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) with an auto incrementing variable as you've done in your code.

```
ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactory(){
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable){
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.setName("C "+counter.getAndIncrement());
        return thread;
    }
};
Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(factory);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I recommend you go over some programming basics before you start jumping into threads. Have two variables named the same way should be an obvious no-no for you.

As for your thread naming code, just do this -

```
Thread thread = new Thread(C++ + "");
```

Note that this only works if whatever is spawning your threads is not concurrent. If it is you need to use `Atmoics`